# What's the easiest way to drop an item?

Tags: diablo-iii

My inventory is starting to run full, and then I accidentally click on the "Cracked Useless Dagger of Bluntness".  I open up my inventory and see the dagger.  Is the only way to drop it to click and drag it off the inventory screen?  Or is there some keyboard/mouse combination that will drop the item without me needing to move my mouse half way across the screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Currently, there is no such shortcut**, though there have been many complaints on the *D3* forums. Click, drag, click.

Or, if you prefer not to move your wrist, click, <kbd>I</kbd>, click to drop, <kbd>I</kbd> (open and close inventory).

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 4):

It is easiest to *not* drop items and instead use the town portal you are granted relatively quickly in the game. Whenever* you're full, you press T, sell non-magic items, salvage magic items, update your stash as needed and jump right back in action.

*Doesn't work in boss levels until after the boss dies.

Comment: I preferred to not pick up garbage items in the first place and if I had a few in my inventory it was most time not worth the trip to the merchant, compared to drag them out on the run. That way you dont need to use the town portal that often, which also saves a lot of time.

Comment: @Nappy I guess I'm more OCD about loot than most are. In Act 1, a full inventory of garbage weapons can net you 50 gold roughly and you can easily full three per 'sub-act'. There's no time limit in the game.

Comment: non-magic trash stays nearly the same value throughout the game, while the value of magic items climbs with level.  Also relative to gold dropped by monsters, it's not at all worth your time to vendor non-magic items

Comment: I agree with @Nappy, I generally try not to pick up none-magic (or higher) items... this has in the past made me walk past some gems not noticing them... but when you do have a handful that slipped in there in your flurry of clicks; just sell them while repairing your equip (you should be repairing it almost every town visit, just for good measure) - then the 300 gold you got for the ten items pays for your repair! :D